# Android read text file in Activity that filters opening text files

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I have Activity that "listening" to open text files, which means in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

So I navigate to file browser, find some text file and try to open it, and as expected this Activity exists on the list of available applications to complete the action. When the activity launches I know the Activity got the correct file name but it treats the file as empty (not printing to the log the content).

Remarks: The file is not empty, other apps can read him, the file path not contains white spaces, no exceptions or crashes.

What i'm doing wrong here?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    //Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && type != null && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleViewText(intent);  //Handle text being sent
    }
}

private void handleViewText(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    //uri.getPath().toString(): /storage/emulated/0/dir/subDir/fileName.txt
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        //This is also not working: br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uri.getPath()));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", sCurrentLine);  //never enters here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //nothing
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first thing first, add `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch block and check if an Exception is throw.

Comment: @Blackbelt As I mentioned in the question ain't exceptions thrown it's tested and the exceptions handle code omitted in purpose of readable question with only relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public String read(String fname){

         BufferedReader br = null;
         String response = null;

            try {

                StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
                String fpath = "/sdcard/"+fname+".txt";

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpath));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.append(line +"n");
                }
                response = output.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;

            }
            return response;

     }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. The `uri` into string is `/storage/emulated/0/dir/subDir/fileName.txt`, so I also omitted from your answer the suffix of `.txt` and it's still not working. The functions return null string but not printing StackTrace.

Comment: Ok...for that you have to find absolute path of the file.

Comment: What do you mean? It's not the path?